# Property doesn't change the value if it assign in a JSInvokable function in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I have an interesting problem. I'm creating a [Markdown Editor component for Blazor](https://github.com/erossini/BlazorMarkdownEditor). The component is working fine. Now, I discover an interesting issue related to a `JSInvokable`. So, the component has a `Value` property

```
[Parameter]
public string Value { get; set; }
```

When I add the component to a page like this

```
<MarkdownEditor Value="@markdownValue" 
                ValueChanged="@OnMarkdownValueChanged"
                ValueHTMLChanged="@OnMarkdownValueHTMLChanged" />

@code {
    string markdownValue = "Test";
}
```

So, in the JavaScript, every time the content changes, I call the JSInvokable via `DotNetObjectReference`.

The function is looking like that ([here](https://github.com/erossini/BlazorMarkdownEditor/blob/a0d06333d82c298c8fa3964ab01cd11a63eed026/PSC.Blazor.Components.MarkdownEditor/MarkdownEditor.razor.cs#L534) the full code)

```
[JSInvokable]
public Task UpdateInternalValue(string value)
{
    Value = value;
    return ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(Value);
}
```

When I debug the function, I can see the new value in the `value`

[image]

Then, I can see the `Value` parameter is changed with the new `value`

[image]

But a line after that `Value` has again the initial value and not the new value from the parameter.

[image]

I don't know if this is something related to the `JSInvokable` function. The interesting thing is in the some function I have another variable `ValueHTML` that changes its value as expected.

Answer (score 2):

This is a variation on "Component changing its Parameter value" , which you shouldn't do.

ValueHTML works because you don't specify it in the owning component. But the `await` there enables the StateHasChanged related logic to refresh `Value` from he surrounding component.

I think you need to do

```
 // Value = value;
```

and let

```
 await ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(Value);
```

make the change, through the owning component.

Comment: I found the way. Thank you for the hint

Answer (score 1):

So, based on the comment from [Henk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60761/henk-holterman), I googled "Component changing its Parameter value" and I found the solution.

In the component, I have to change the `Value` parameter like that

```
[Parameter]
public string Value {
    get => _value;
    set
    {
        if (_value == value) return;
        _value = value;

        ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
    }
}
private string _value;
```

Then, in the page, I call the component with a `bind-Value`

```
<MarkdownEditor @bind-Value="@markdownValue" 
                ValueHTMLChanged="@OnMarkdownValueHTMLChanged" />
```

Comment: **Very VERY bad idea**.  You should never put code into [Parameter] properties on components.  They should be `[Parameter] public string Value {get; set;}`.  It slows the whole render process down.  I'm post an answer in a while once I've been through your code (or enet will beat me to it!)

Comment: Agreed, you shouldn't mess with `Value`. Bind to a private property inside your component and implement the logic in its `set{  }`.

Answer (score 1):

In `UpdateInternalValue`:

```cs
Value = value;
//....
ValueHTMLChanged.InvokeAsync(ValueHTML);
return ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(Value);
```

1. You set Value.  You shouldn't do this - This is bad practice.
2. You async invoke the `ValueHTMLChanged` event callback.
3. This calls `OnMarkdownValueHTMLChanged` in the parent.
4. This triggers a `StateHasChanged` event in the parent.
5. The Renderer calls `SetParamatersAsync` on the component
6. Value is set back to the old value of `markdownValue`.  It hasn't yet been updated!
7. You're now back in the code block and async invoke the `ValueChanged` event callback.
8. repeat steps 3....5  In 6 `markdownValue` is set to the new value so shows correctly.

You're living in the async world: things don't get run in a nice sequential order.

Don't set Value. I think, if I've read the code right, it will get updated as part of calling `ValueChanged` and the triggered component rendering process.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't understand what you suggest to change.

Comment: See last paragraph.  Remove `Value = value` from `UpdateInternalValue`.   You shouldn't need it, and shouldn't be doing it. :-)